# jQuery draggable option elements

Tags: jquery

Any tips on making the following option elements draggable?

```
<select id="expenseSelect" multiple="multiple" style="height:200px">
    <option value="a">aaaaaaaa</option>
    <option value="b">bbbbbbbb</option>
    <option value="c">cccccccc</option>
    <option value="d">dddddddd</option>
    <option value="e">eeeeeeee</option>
</select>
```

The following doesn't seem to work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#expenseSelect').children().draggable();
});
```

I'm basically looking for a listbox element where the user can choose 1 or more items and drag them to a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible with the native drop-down boxes. Different browsers may create a `select` tags in different ways. For example, mobile devices are likely to do something completely different with `select` tags.

You should perhaps look at using a jQuery plugin (or creating your own) which makes a drop down box using `div` or `li` tags instead. These could then be draggable.

Comment: Hmm... I would recommend writing a plugin *only* if there are no plugins that already do this. It saves you from re inventing the wheel. jQuery UI handles this quite nicely!

Comment: I having trouble selecting multiple objects when using `div` and `li` tags.

Comment: I do like plugins, but only if they work perfectly! Its much easier to fix bugs in your own code ;) Most plugins do much more that what you need them to anyway. I tend to write my own plugins for simple tasks. Saves much more time in the future!

Comment: @Max, could you not find a plugin that supports selecting multiple items?

Comment: Nothing at first, I'll take another look.

Answer (score 4):

Faced with this problem, and wrote a small jQuery plugin for that. Only problem is Internet Explorer (any) - it not support any events on <option> element.

https://github.com/NikitaKA/jquery.dragOptions

Comment: @quickshiftin I'm pleased that after 3 years it was useful. :)

Comment: Thanks :). Works like charm

Answer (score 1):

jQuery draggable will not work a dropdown element like this. I would recommend using a unordered list `<ul>` to display the data, as jQuery can reorder something like this.

Also you are probably looking for "sortable", since you want to drag new items into the list, not "draggable". Look at the source code for this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a `select` option to draggable with jQuery.

[Look at the draggable Docs to see how you can do what **you** want to do](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) (albeit without the use of the `select` box)