# Drag & drop only one item from one select to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have 2 `select` :

```
<div class="bold margin-bottom-10"> 
     Departments possible
     <span style="margin-left: 16%;">Departments selected</span>
</div>

<select name="departmentsSelectable" id="departmentsSelectable" multiple="true">                    
    <option value="1" class="item draggable">Java 1</option>
    <option value="2" class="item draggable">Java 2</option>
    <option value="3" class="item draggable">Java 3</option>
</select>

<select name="departments" id="departments" class="droppable" multiple="true" style="margin-left: 3%;"></select>
```

Which is giving the view :

[image: View in the browser]

But unfortunately, I don't master JQuery enough to understand these drag/drop events and how to manage them easily :/ I do not know neither, how to put a restriction to have one and only one item.

Here is the fiddly of this problem : http://jsfiddle.net/h90j6xy4/1/

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to @[saravanan-mp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1624626/saravanan-mp), I plugged http://loudev.com/#demos.

**Here is the new fiddly : http://jsfiddle.net/h90j6xy4/3/**.

But still, I would like to have a drag & drop effect, and to be able to select only 1 element, and I still don't know how to do it

Comment: Do you want exmple like this http://loudev.com/#demos

Comment: In your example, one click is enough to switch from one list to another.
I would like to have the drag&drop event. But beside of this, yep that's perfectly what I want :)

Comment: @saravanan-mp look a the Edit, I plug your Jquery pluggin, and it's indeed starts to look very good.
But still, the condition of my question are not fill :/ how to block more than 1 element, and how to have the drag & drop effect :/

Comment: This question might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086111/jquery-draggable-option-elements