# How i can drag a <select> tag?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using HTML helper `@html.ListboxFor` which is creating `<select>` tags. I want to drag these `<select>` tags and want to drop on textarea. But jquery draggable is not working. How I can achieve this please help me.

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.DependancyMatrixVM.Real_Tag_Id_FK(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RawTagList, new { @class = "form-control add_item", @multiple = true, id = "Raw_Tag_List", onChange = "selectedTagListFun()" })


 $("#DevRaw_Tag_List option").draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone",
                cursor: "move",
                revert: "invalid"
            });
```

Comment: First error I spotted is that your id param in ListBoxFor is "Raw_Tag_List" but you seem to pass "#DevRaw_Tag_List" in jquery selector.

Comment: Check answer in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086111/jquery-draggable-option-elements

Comment: @YigitalpErtem this does not error I just paste small part of my code.